# Stopwatch not displaying Full Time - Missing Last Digit

Tags: javascript

I have a stopwatch here, but it only displays 11:11:10 (0 staying as zero, and 1 being a changing(increasing) number). How can I fix this?

This is my Code:

```js
var timer = document.getElementById('timer'); //Here is where I grab the html - no problems here 
var time = 0;
var running = 0;

document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    timer.style.color = "white";
    start();
  }
}

function start() {
  if (running == 0) {
    reset();
    running = 1;
    increment();
  } else {
    running = 0;
  }
}

function reset() {
  running = 0;
  time = 0;
  timer.innerHTML = "00:00:00";
}

function increment() {
  if (running == 1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      time++;
      var mins = Math.floor(time / 10 / 60);
      if (mins <= 9) {
        mins = "0" + mins;
      }
      var secs = Math.floor(time / 10);
      if (secs <= 9) {
        secs = "0" + secs;
      }
      var tenths = Math.floor(time % 10);
      if (tenths <= 9) {
        tenths = tenths;
      }
//The hundredths part is experimental - I’m confused how to do it which is the whole question
      var hundreths = Math.floor(time % 100);
      timer.innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs + ":" + tenths + Math.floor(time / 1000 / 60);
      increment();
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">00:00:00</div>

<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start()">
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset()">
```

The full project is here if you want to see it. I’m making a speedcube timer:

https://speedcube-timer.coderguru.repl.co/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Might have something to do with the timeout running every tenth of a second.

Comment: FYI - You may also notice the timer run slow as `setInterval` and `setTimeout` are not precise.

Comment: The minutes increment at 60 seconds but don't get reset!

Comment: When I run the Code, the seconds work fine. I’m looking at the second digit of the milliseconds - basically the hundredths

Comment: All your code works to the assumption that time is counting tenths of a second. The hundredths will always be zero.

Comment: So how exactly can I fix this - I’m no good at JS so I’m still a bit confused - sorry if I’m irritating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's you code modified to run every 1 hundredth of a second rather than every tenth.

Also, it's not calculating tenths and hundredths separately and calculates the minutes correctly as well (`% 60`).

```js
var timer = document.getElementById('timer'); //Here is where I grab the html - no problems here 
var time = 0;
var running = 0;

document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    timer.style.color = "white";
    start();
  }
}

function start() {
  if (running == 0) {
    reset();
    running = 1;
    increment();
  } else {
    running = 0;
  }
}

function reset() {
  running = 0;
  time = 0;
  timer.innerHTML = "00:00.00";
}

function increment() {
  if (running == 1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      time++;
      var mins = Math.floor(time / 100 / 60);
      if (mins <= 9) {
        mins = "0" + mins;
      }
      var secs = Math.floor(time / 100 % 60);
      if (secs <= 9) {
        secs = "0" + secs;
      }
      
      var hundredths = Math.floor(time % 100);
      if (hundredths <= 9) {
        hundredths = "0" + hundredths;
      }
      
      timer.innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs + "." + hundredths;
      increment();
    }, 10);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">00:00:00</div>

<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start()">
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset()">
```

**NOTE:**
This method of counting time is quite naive. Due to the way `setInterval` and `setTimeout` schedule the callback you're likely to see a fair amount of drift (slow) with this. Also, the browser is likely to not run the callback if another window/tab has focus.

Fixing that though would be a different question ;o)

Comment: does this follow real time speed?

Comment: when i compared with windows timer for 1 minute , i got only 56:31 using this script.

Comment: It's as close as it's going to get doing it this way due to the way `setTimeout` and `setInterval` work. Fairly sure I've answered a similar question previously...

Comment: Can't find it now but you'd have to calculate what time had elapsed since the timer started using the system time but that's a different question!

Comment: Using global time works much better - using timeouts ended up being very inaccurate for me, losing 15s in 1 Minute